# Why does this sleeping barber solution not cause a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

Considering the sleeping barber problem, we have the following solution where we have two condition variables `customer_available` and `barber_available` in the monitor:

```
get_haircut
    if num_free_chairs > 0
    then
        num_free_chairs := num_free_chairs - 1
        customer_available.signal
        barber_available.wait

do_haircut 
    if num_free_chairs = N
    then 
        customer_available.wait
    barber_available.signal
    num_free_chairs := num_free_chairs + 1
```

Now, assume that the first customer goes in and calls the `customer_available_signal` and wakes the barber up; then assume that the barber thread starts and executes the complete function and starts to wait on `customer_available` again (assume that another thread calling the `do_haircut` method again and again). And context switches and then the customer thread also stucks on `barber_available` condition causing a deadlock. So, this solution seemed wrong to me, however it is the same in several different sources.

Is it because that the methods in the monitor are atomic and the customer is guaranteed to call `customer_available.signal` and `barber_available.wait` sequentially before the barber thread continues to execution?

Comment: Monitors only allow one procedure to be executing at a time.  That's how they synchronize execution.  So the scenario you propose can't happen.  `get_haircut` must run until it terminates or hits the barber available wait before `do_haircut` can start.